# Meteor isopacket ddp load error

Tags: javascript, meteor

Background: running windows 10 and meteor 1.3.3

```
C:\Users\lisa-_000\Documents\simple-todos>meteor
[[[[[ C:\Users\lisa-_000\Documents\simple-todos ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
Errors prevented isopacket load:

While loading isopacket `ddp`:
module.js:338:15: Cannot find module './_baseClone'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous>
(C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\ddp\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\node_modules\babel-types\node_modules\lodash\clone.js:1:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Module.Mp.load
(C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous>
(C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\ddp\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\node_modules\babel-types\lib\index.js:314:38)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Module.Mp.load
(C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous>
(C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\ddp\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\node_modules\babel-template\lib\index.js:84:43)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Module.Mp.load
(C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous>
(C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\ddp\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\lib\index.js:525:46)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Module.Mp.load
(C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object._.extend.Npm.require (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1570:22)
at Object.require (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1547:11)
at Package (packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:17:1)
at packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:356:1
at packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:356:1


=> Errors prevented startup:

   While loading plugin `compile-ecmascript` from package `ecmascript`:
   module.js:338:15: Cannot find module './_baseClone'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\ecmascript\0.4.4\plugin.compile-ecmascript.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\node_modules\babel-types\node_modules\lodash\clone.js:1:17)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Module.Mp.load
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\ecmascript\0.4.4\plugin.compile-ecmascript.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\node_modules\babel-types\lib\index.js:314:38)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Module.Mp.load
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\ecmascript\0.4.4\plugin.compile-ecmascript.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\node_modules\babel-template\lib\index.js:84:43)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Module.Mp.load
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\ecmascript\0.4.4\plugin.compile-ecmascript.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\lib\index.js:525:46)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Module.Mp.load
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object._.extend.Npm.require (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1570:22)
   at Object.require (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1547:11)
   at Package (packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:17:1)
   at packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:356:1
   at packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:356:1


   While loading plugin `compileTemplatesBatch` from package `templating`:
   module.js:338:15: Cannot find module './_baseClone'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\templating\1.1.10\plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\node_modules\babel-types\node_modules\lodash\clone.js:1:17)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Module.Mp.load
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\templating\1.1.10\plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\node_modules\babel-types\lib\index.js:314:38)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Module.Mp.load
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\templating\1.1.10\plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\node_modules\babel-template\lib\index.js:84:43)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Module.Mp.load
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\templating\1.1.10\plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\lib\index.js:525:46)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Module.Mp.load
   (C:\Users\lisa-_000\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object._.extend.Npm.require (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1570:22)
   at Object.require (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1547:11)
   at Package (packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:17:1)
   at packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:356:1
   at packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:356:1


=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I used meteor months ago then got rid of it. I decided to begin a new project 2 days ago so I reinstalled it. When I tried running meteor I got some error which after some google searches I realised I was still running an old version. I tried updating from the command line which went on for hours in multiple attempts and never finished. I uninstalled and reinstalled using the windows installer which still took hours and multiple attempts. I then got some new errors as shown above. Based on a response to a similar question I deleted the emacscript and templating packages then reran meteor which then installed the now missing packages and that got rid of those last 2 errors.

The first error however never disappeared I just ignored it because it ran anyway. However when I tried typing:

```
meteor add reactive-dict
```

this isopacket error appeared again and prevented the package from being added. So if I try to add any code using that it ofcourse says module not found. So once again I uninstalled meteor and reinstalled using the windows installer but now I'm back to square one! Wondering if anyone has had this experience or has any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reported as [Meteor issue #7221](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7221) that appeared in v1.3.3. It appears to be a Windows specific problem and happens with the most basic apps. I'd bet they are fast at work on 1.3.3.1.

In the meantime, you might get some mileage by reverting to 1.3.2.4 using "meteor update --release 1.3.2.4".

Comment: thanks! I was trying that earlier but it was taking so long that I said I'd just leave it overnight tonight

Comment: Can confirm that this worked for me using the same platform and version. Thanks!